# How is the sample size for a given population determined?

Tags: sampling, sample-size, error

The following passage is an excerpt from [*Thinking, Fast and Slow* by Daniel Kahnemann](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11468377-thinking-fast-and-slow)

> The risk of error can be estimated for any given sample size by a
>   *fairly simple procedure*. Traditionally, however, psychologists do not
>   use calculations to decide on a sample size. They use their judgment,
>   which is commonly flawed. An article I had read shortly before the
>   debate with Amos demonstrated the mistake that researchers made (they
>   still do) by a dramatic observation. The author pointed out that
>   psychologists commonly chose samples so small that they exposed
>   themselves to a 50% risk of failing to confirm their true hypotheses!
>
> Like most research psychologists, I had routinely chosen samples that
>   were too small and had often obtained results that made no sense. Now
>   I knew why: the odd results were actually artifacts of my research
>   method. My mistake was particularly embarrassing because I taught
>   statistics and knew how to compute the sample size that would reduce
>   the risk of failure to an acceptable level.

What is the procedure for determining the sample size and the error?

Comment: This is called power analysis or 'performing a power study'. For a given significance level and effect size, different from zero, one chooses a minimum power (probability of rejection) at that point; this then [determines the minimum required sample size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_size_determination). [One might then usefully examine the entire power curve - but I don't often see this done.] I think the comments that it doesn't happen much were once true, but considering power seems to be pretty common (even standard) in psychology, and has been for a good long time now.

Comment: No doubt someone who works in psychology could say much more than me about the circumstances that currently prevail and what steps are usually taken.  (I know we have several active or occasionaly-active members in that category)